# What is the difference between finding the mid in the following two different ways

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

For a divide and conquer algorithm in an array, we need to be able to find the middle element of a range. The obvious way to do that is `mid = (leftSide + rightSide) / 2`. However, I've heard that that way is not correct, and that we need to write `mid = leftSide + (rightSide - leftSide) / 2` instead. Can someone explain the difference between those two?

Comment: @ruakh By adding the array search context you rather ruled out negative values, while the original didn't...

Comment: @KellyBundy: Interesting point! (Though for the record, the question was tagged [binary-search] even before my edit.) I think it's fine, though, for two main reasons: (1) the question was originally tagged [binary-search-tree], which doesn't make sense, but supports the assumption that the OP was thinking of binary search and just didn't have quite the right term; and (2) the OP's corrected version only helps avoid overflow if `leftSide` and `rightSide` have the same sign (otherwise it can actually *introduce* overflow!).

Comment: @ruakh Binary search, yes, but I think it didn't say arrays. I've written plenty of binary searches on integer ranges unrelated to array indexes, probably including some that included negatives. And negatives can make [another difference, due to rounding rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70117833/what-is-the-difference-between-finding-the-mid-in-the-following-two-different-wa?noredirect=1#comment123991490_70117937). Good point (2), though.

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry for the tagging of binary search but it is better to say divide and concur than binary search I will update it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `(leftSide + rightSide) /2` can overflow, depending on the language and data types you are using and the values of `leftSide` and `rightSide`. The reason is that you first add `leftSide` and `rightSide` and then divide them by 2.

While in this method `leftSide + (rightSide - leftSide)/2` you subtract and divide them by 2 and then add leftSide, which can make a difference in some cases.

Other than that, those expressions are mathematically identical as follows:

```
leftSide + (rightSide - leftSide)/2
2leftSide/2 + (rightSide - leftSide)/2
(2leftSide + rightSide - leftSide)/2
(rightSide + leftSide)/2
```

On request of OP, I am adding a concrete Java example on how `(leftSide + rightSide) / 2` can overflow.

Suppose we are storing `left` and `right` in java `int`s which are 4 byte signed integers. This means that they cover `-2^31` to `2^31-1`. Now, further suppose that we have `0` and `2147483000` as our left and right. Keep in mind that our upper bound is only slightly less than the 4 byte signed integer's upper limit of `2^31-1 = 2147483647`. After the first search, since target lies on the right side, left becomes `1073741501`, because `2147483000 / 2 + 1 = 1073741501`. Now at this point using the formula `(left + right) / 2` is dangerous. Because:

```
left =  2147483000 / 2 + 1 = 1073741501
right = 2147483000
left + right = 3221224501
```

So, `left + right` is above the available limit/bits for an unsigned 4 byte integers. What happens is that Java interprets the new integers as negative since the most significant bit which shows the sign is set. Consider the following example:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int right = 2147483647;
        int left = 1073741500;
        
        System.out.println(left + " " + right);
        System.out.println(left + right);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1073741500 2147483647
-1073742149
```

Long story short, you can avoid this situation by using `leftSide + (rightSide - leftSide)/2`. Since you subtract left from right first and the divide by 2, there is no risk of overflow.

If you are further interested, [here's a blog post](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) by a Google Research engineer on how prevalent this bug in binary search is.

Comment: can you give me a little bit explanation considering java as a programming language

Comment: I've updated the answer since it was not possible to write it here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for all `L` and `R`,

```
(L + R) / 2 = (2.L - L + R) / 2 = L + (R - L) / 2.
```

using integer arithmetic. Hence there is no difference (except in case of overflow or negative numbers; then even division by 2 or right-shift may yield different results).

Comment: @KellyBundy: right, I noticed but didn't finish the edit. Done now.

Comment: Now it makes more sense, but I'd say it doesn't really add something the other answer didn't already. Also, there's [another possible difference](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JVXBJjO/uKQoNTHXjosrM69EITcxM09DU6GaS0EBxPVRsFXQNdVRCALSRtZAweKSFCur5PzSEgUbGwUNHwVthSBNBX0FIxAXLJeal5KDoRCkTiNIQVfBB5vi2v//AQ) that I would've thought you'd realize, given your original answer :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: you are quire right. I did not mention this because array indexes use to be non-negative, but there can indeed be circumstances when they are not.

Comment: Yes, array indexes are usually non-negative (I think I've never done binary search with negative array indexes), but occasionally we search number ranges that have nothing to do with array indexes and then it's not that unlikely. (And the array search context was only recently edited into the question by someone other than the OP).

Comment: @KellyBundy: every now & then, I use shifted indexes, for example for symmetry (`base= &array[middle_index]`). Now offsets can be negative.

Division and modulo are done by default with rounding towards 0; I wish it was towards -∞, this is often a better choice.